# En esta historia, ¿quiénes estuvieron en el baile en Tepic?

Tags: gramática, significado, historia

Comprender el párrafo corto en las letras negras me está costando. La fuente es un [documento primario](http://www.pim.unam.mx/catalogos/hyd/HYDIV/HYDIV069.pdf) de la época de la independencia de México. Quizás hace falta puntuación, pero fue transcrito por académicos de la UNAM en un gran projecto sistemático. Bueno, ya sé que el "ameritado caudillo" fue Torres, y creo que el indultado fue Merino, pero **¿quiénes estuvieron en el baile en Tepic?**

> ...
>
> Con este motivo, Cruz destinó al teniente coronel don Pedro Celestino Negrete, para
>   que con la mejor división de los reales ejércitos de su mando, persiguiera exclusivamente a Torres. Así lo hizo, y a consecuencia de esa persecución, el valeroso insurgente se decidió a atacar al diestro y perito coronel. Salió de Uruáparo y atacó a Negrete cerca del pueblo de Tlasasalca el día 2 de mayo, mas habiendo sido derrotado, tuvo que huir, y perseguido por los comandantes Arango y López Merino, fue aprehendido por este último en "Palo Alto" en la madrugada del día 4 de abril de 1812.
>
> **La aprehensión de este ameritado caudillo fue muy justamente celebrada, dando
>   Merino que fue insurgente algún tiempo y se indultó, por haberle conseguido el indulto del
>   general Cruz su esposa, en un baile en Tepic, el siguiente parte a don Pedro Celestino
>   Negrete, que lo remitió a Cruz y éste al virrey en estos términos:**
>
> “Excelentísimo señor.⎯ Con muy particular satisfacción traslado a vuestra señoría
>   el parte que he recibido del teniente coronel don Pedro Negrete, comandante de la primera
>   división de este ejército y a la letra es como sigue:
>
> ‘Anoche a las ocho di a vuestra señoría parte de que salía para sorprender al
>   conquistador Torres que en Tupátaro reunía nueva gavilla, y mi satisfacción es completa,
>   como de toda la división, el enérgico e interesante del siempre bizarro y muy acreditado
>   comandante de la guerrilla teniente Merino.⎯ Mi comandante: sorprendí al viejo Torres, lo
>   hice prisionero, por haber mandado a la tropa que no lo matase para entregarlo a usted vivo. De toda su chusma que se componía de cuatrocientos, los que no murieron a los filos de las bayonetas, *murieron asados por haber quemado yo* las trojes donde se metieron. Quedó todo su armamento en mi poder y toda su remonta; sólo he sacado al sargento Estrada
>   gravemente herido, lo que me ha sido bastante sensible. Dios guarde a usted muchos años.
>   Palo Alto abril 4 de 1812.⎯ A las tres de la mañana.⎯ *José Antonio López Merino*.⎯
>   Señor don Pedro Celestino Negrete. -Se lo enviaré a vuestra señoría vivo para que pague en
>   esa ciudad parte de sus *innumerables delitos*. Dios guarde a vuestra señoría muchos años. Pilas de Arechipo a legua y media de distancia de Palo Alto, a 4 de abril de 1812.⎯ *Pedro Celestino Negrete*.⎯ A las cinco de la mañana.⎯ Señor general don José de la Cruz.’
>
> ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podemos simplificar la frase en negrita como

> En un baile en Tepec, Merino dio el parte a don Pedro Celestino Negrete.

Recordemos que el original era

> dando Merino [que fue insurgente algún tiempo y se indultó, por
>   haberle conseguido el indulto del general Cruz su esposa,] en un baile
>   en Tepic, el siguiente parte a don Pedro Celestino Negrete

Arriba entre corchetes [], señalo la oración subordinada adjetiva, la cual puede quitarse y es fácil entender la oración.

Pareciera que la esposa estuvo en el baile también dado el siguiente fragmento

> por haberle conseguido el indulto del general Cruz su esposa, en un
>   baile en Tepic

Pero creo que debe entenderse la explicativa entre comas por sí misma «por haberle conseguido el indulto del general Cruz su esposa» de manera que «en un baile en Tepic» es complemento de lugar de la oración principal y no de la subordinada.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Fue el "su esposa" que me tenía enredado.